# SELECT DISTINCT, trying to pull from a join, need unique results

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

Two tables are in question; `leads`and `contactAttempts`.

I'm trying to pull distinct leads that were contacted in 2012, with specific keywords from a text column on a separate table.

The problem is that I keep getting the same lead ids over and over, and the results are so massive that it is timing out and crashing the website.

I've tried multiple variations, including all in one sql statement. Separating them into 2 sql statements is my latest iteration at an attempt.

Select distinct is not currently working in the format I'm trying.  `id` is the primary in both tables, `leadID` connects `leads` to `contactAttempts`:

```
<? $sql="SELECT * 
 FROM contactAttempts a
 JOIN leads l
 ON l.id = a.leadID  
 WHERE l.agentID = 2 
 AND l.leadType IN(0,2)
 AND a.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 23:59:59' 
 LIMIT 0,50";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $sql2="SELECT DISTINCT leadID FROM contactAttempts WHERE 
leadID='$row[id]' AND (contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%shown%' OR 
contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%showed%' OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE 
'%offer%' OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%inspection%' OR 
contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%appraisal%' OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE 
'%closing%' OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%drive%' OR 
contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%drove%' OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%car%' 
OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%preview%' OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE 
'%previewed%' OR contactAttempts.notes LIKE '%took pictures%') LIMIT 1";
    $res2=mysql_query($sql2);$x=0;
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
        $x++;
        echo $x.' - '.$row2['leadID'];
        echo '<br />';
    }
} ?>
```

Here's a source example:
table leads:

id - 100, bunch of other columns not useful to this script

id - 200, bunch of other columns not useful to this script

table contactAttempts:

id - 1, leadID - 100, notes - 'Showed house to customer, they liked it', timestamp - '2012-01-21 12:05:11'

id - 2, leadID - 100, notes - 'Showed house to customer again, they liked it', timestamp - '2012-02-21 12:05:11'

id - 3, leadID - 200, notes - 'Showed house to a different customer, they hated it', timestamp - '2012-01-21 12:05:11'

Right now, the results would be: 100,100,200.  I need the results to be 100,200.  The script needs to omit multiple occurrences of leadID 100.

Comment: so your question is not how to improve your query and logic? but just how to get next 50 records?

Comment: the limit 0,50 was to stop the script from crashing, it is meaningless to the complete picture

Comment: so what is your problem? in 2nd query you just query `LIMIT 1` one record if you need another one - remove LIMIT. if you need something else clarify your requirements. your queries must be optimized for sure, but that is not what you are asking for so far?

Comment: The second query is still running 50 times since it is in the loop of the first query, I put a limit 1 in to attempt a fix, but I was still getting the same leadID multiple times, when I only want to see it come through once

Comment: give us example of your source data and expected result. so far it seems that you expect different ids. but you didn't **select distinct id** and not **group by id** so your query is just takes some rows even if id has duplicates.

Comment: so you don't need other columns from contactAttempts except `id` and `leadID`? and even `id` is out of your zone of interest?

Comment: correct, just need leadID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? 
$sql="
 SELECT 
    l.id as id,
    a.id as attempt_id,
    a.leadID as leadID,
 FROM leads l
 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT id, leadID
     FROM contactAttempts 
     WHERE contactAttempts.notes REGEXP 'shown|showed|offer|inspection|appraisal|closing|drive|drove|car|preview|previewed|took pictures' 
     AND timestamp BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
    ) as a
 ON a.leadID = l.id
 WHERE l.agentID = 2 
   AND l.leadType IN(0,2)
 ORDER BY l.id, a.id
 ";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$currLead = 0;
$x=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    if ($currLead != $row['leadID']){
        echo 'NEW DISTINCT LEAD = '.$row['leadID'].'<br />';
        $x=0;
    }
    $x++;
    echo $x.' of lead '.$row['leadID'].'  attempt '.$row['attempt_id'];
    echo '<br />';
    $currLead = $row['leadID'];
} ?>
```

Comment: Was kind of hoping to eliminate the redundancy in the sql, it's a very heavy mysql script (there are over 150k rows in the leads table).  This does run without crashing my page though

Answer (score 0):

Before I (or others) get to solving the actual problem; some observations on your first query.

First, that query is (I believe) logically identical to the following, which I find easier to read:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM contactAttempts a
  JOIN leads l
    ON l.id = a.leadID  
 WHERE l.agentID = 2 
   AND l.leadType IN(0,2)
   AND YEAR(a.timestamp) = 2012 
 LIMIT 0,50
```

Secondly, YEAR() prevents the use of index, so on larger datasets this will slow things down considerably. `a.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 23:59:59'` may look cumbersome but it will be much faster on indexed data.

Thirdly, LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Also, and equally, `LIKE '%...'` cannot use an index, although `LIKE '...%'` can